# CSS Image sprite

Tags: html, css

I have to replace image in the image frame from sprite sheet. But right now images are moving one by one. I have also attached my image in png format

```css
.guy {
  height: 190px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(sprite_sheet.png);
}

#guy-1 {
  -webkit-animation: run-x 10s infinite steps(100);
}

@-webkit-keyframes run-x {
  from {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position-y: -1950px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Keyframes check</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="guy-1" class="guy"></div>

  <a href="sprite_sheet.png" target="_BLANK">Original sprite</a>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: `run-x` but to `background-position-y: -1950px;`. Maybe to `background-position-x: -1950px;`?

Comment: @sumi your question might need some extra word to make clear what's ur problem